# Sitecore Razl Script connection error

Tags: powershell, razl

I am starting the `Sitecore Razl` scripting and trying to get an item by using script as mentioned in the documentation.

https://hedgehogdevelopment.github.io/razl/script.html

So my script goes like this:-

```
import-module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Sitecore\Razl\HedgehogDevelopment.RazlClient.dll" -verbose   
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('RAZL_LICENSE_KEY',<MyLicenseKey>)
$connection = Get-RazlConnection -SitecoreWebUrl <MySitecoreWebUrl> -DatabaseName master -AccessGuid <myAccessGuid>
Get-RazlItem -Connection $connection -ItemID "{6A148A08-B363-4C50-9DE7-6F38GHI054JK}"
```

and getting the below error :-

```
Get-RazlItem : The activation was rejected by the server.
At line:5 char:1
+ Get-RazlItem -Connection $connection -ItemID "{6A148A08-B363-4C50-9DE ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-RazlItem], LicenseFailureException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetItem: An error occured when checking for a license @ 1/13/2023 3:32:12 AM. The error message is: The activation was rejected by the server..,HedgehogDevelopment.RazlClient.CmdLets.GetItem

Get-RazlItem : Could not find Razl License. Please run Razl.exe and add/update your license.
```

Any ideas or thoughts on why this error is coming up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the same setup of Razl on my local for Sitecore 10.1 version. Here is my script.

```
import-module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Sitecore\Razl\HedgehogDevelopment.RazlClient.dll" -verbose   
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('RAZL_LICENSE_KEY','my-license-key')
$connection = Get-RazlConnection -SitecoreWebUrl 'https://sitecore10.1sc.dev.local/' -DatabaseName master -AccessGuid '8d92797d-2d19-4ec5-a4f1-b10750c98872'
Get-RazlItem -Connection $connection -ItemID "{27F07929-9DF9-4E3E-9AC3-809AE7EBACCA}"
```

And I am able to get a response like this.

[image]

After investigating, I found a similar issue mentioned in the article. So according to the article if the error you see of Razl License is like this.

**An error occurred when checking for a license @ . The error message is: The activation was rejected by the server.**

The issue will be this.

**Razl also logs information for problems occurring when communicating with the license server or the license key. If you see the above error, there's probably another installation of Razl using the same license key, or there's a problem with the key itself. In this case, please contact the Hedgehog support team.**

Read more

https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Blog/razl-log-files

So the script is working fine and the issue is with your license.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Sumit. I will take it up to Sitecore to deal with licensing.